# Coupon API not working for guest user in Magento 2 core API

Tags: magento2, api, coupon

I Followed below steps,
1. Create cart for guest user
URL:  http://devsite.com/magento2.2/rest/all/V1/guest-carts

```
   Content-Type: application/json
   Method: POST
   Authorization Bearer Key: yfna0bkjnj3j8jcr42rk7a1f3391yy0c

   Request Parameters: NIL

   Response :
adf748e2e78b4cd4d7d3795a127bed97  (Generates Cart ID in response)
```

2. create coupon in backend and also by API
3. Apply this coupon to cartId

URL:  http://devsite.com/magento2.2/rest/all/V1/guest-carts/adf748e2e78b4cd4d7d3795a127bed97/coupons/782OYX2VOEINUF08

```
   Content-Type: application/json
   Method: PUT
   Authorization Bearer Key: yfna0bkjnj3j8jcr42rk7a1f3391yy0c

   Request Parameters: NIL

   Response :
{
 "message": "Coupon code is not valid"
}
```

For check I have applied this coupon in front-end of website as a guest user its work. In API only its not working

Answer (score 0):

Follow the URL for this issue,
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14056